# 'Creating default object from empty value' appears when filtering fields

Tags: laravel-5, octobercms, octobercms-backend

i am trying to change field label dynamically base on username that starts with specific string

```
public function filterFields($fields,$context = null)
{
      $nager = WartaDataProfil::where('backend_users_id',$this->getBackendUserId())->pluck('nager');        

      if(Str::startsWith($nager[0],'GP')){            

        $fields->wil->label = "Sektor";
      }

}
```

i got error

> Creating default object from empty value

from line

```
$fields->wil->label = "Sektor";
```

when i `dd($fields->wil->label);` i got default string which is defined in yaml file..

fields.yaml

```
fields:
nowarta:
    label: 'No. Warta'
    ...
tanggal:
    label: 'Tanggal'
    ...
batasno:
    label: ''
    ...
    type: section           
tabs:
fields:
    renung:
        label: 'Renungan Mingguan'            
        span: full
        type: section 
        tab: 'Renungan/Artikel'           
    renungan:
        label: ''            
        ...  
        type: repeater
        ...
        minItems: '1'
        maxItems: '1'        
        form:
            fields:
                judul:
                    label: 'Judul'                        
                    ...
                bacaan:
                    label: 'Bahan'
                    ...

                penulis:
                    label: 'Penulis'                        
                    ...                      
                isi:
                    label: Renungan                        
                    ...
    keb:
        label: 'Kebaktian Umum'
        span: full
        type: section  
        tab: 'Kebaktian'                                
    kebakti:
        label: ''            
        span: full
        type: partial
        path: field_kebum
        tab: 'Kebaktian' 
    kom: 
        label: 'Kebaktian Komisi'
        span: left
        type: section  
        tab: 'Kebaktian'
    wil: <<<   THIS FIELD <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        label: 'Persekutuan Wilayah'            
        span: right
        type: section
        tab: 'Kebaktian'                  
    Komisi:
        label: ''            
        span: left
        type: partial
        path: field_kebkom
        tab: 'Kebaktian'       
    pwil:
        label: ''                     
        span: right
        type: partial
        path: field_pwilayah
        tab: 'Kebaktian'
```

hope this help to get solution for my problem.. because i use the same filterField in other model and its working fine..

Comment: hmm can you share more info about error, `on which like its raising` and `under which scenario`, I have  try to reproduce it `but seems for me everything works fine`.

Comment: That fields is tabfields so could this be the scenario that you mean?

Comment: yes may be let me check that as well, i mean that during insert, during update or any usual time like ajax when you get error like that

Comment: I checked field which was inside tab and seems working for me `$fields->description1->label = 'oks';` its enough for me

Comment: Well.. the model has `public function beforeSave()` and has many partial field..

Comment: are you able to share `fields.yaml` file content.

Comment: Sure.. i'll update my question

Comment: hmm anything else is causing issue , I used your `fields.yaml` `$fields->wil->label = 'oks';` worked fine, can you share on which line this error occurs may be assigning label is not issue somethings else may be

Comment: Could  repeater field cause this issue.. since i had this filterField function on other model and it work very well.. and on that other model didnt have repeater field..

Comment: Could function `extendFormFieldBefore` in the controller cause this issue..

Comment: if you can share `code` i can look that up

Comment: I will try to disable additional function that has beed added to  models and controller and i let know which function that cause this issue..

Comment: hmm ! that seems plan :)

Comment: i got it.. i remove all the repeater field.. and everything working like a charm.. is there a way to deal with this repeater field.. is it a bug ?

Comment: not sure repeater is done using js client side so may be .. you need to pock there i guess :)

Comment: I redo the yaml file.. so i use relationWidget instead of repeater.. and it works well..

Comment: kudos to that, great

Comment: I post this issue in github for octobercms.. one solution came up that it need to use bindEvent.. i tried but nothing happen.. so i thats why i redo yaml file

Comment: Thank you @HardikSatasiya for your advise so far.. really help me a lot..

Comment: most welcome @isral :)